# Prove directly that $ \ (n+1)^3 \geq 3^n , \ \ n \leq 4 \ $ .

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

Prove directly that $ \ (n+1)^3 \geq 3^n , \ \ n \leq 4 \ $ .

**Answer:**

I can prove it by putting $ \ n=1,2,3,4 \ \ $ .  But I need a formal proof .

**Is there any help?**

Comment: The question's child's play, you already have a formal proof - by _exhaustion!_

Comment: I did not get you. can you do little ? May be it is easy but I cant't catch it right now

Comment: You've tested all the valid $n$'s.  There are no more cases to prove. If there are a finite number of cases, testing each case _is_ a formal proof.

Comment: take a calculator and consider $n=5$

Comment: that is  a formal proof, you have exhausted all possibilities and shown the inequality is valid

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner What does $n = 5$ have to do with anything?

Comment: for $n\geq 5$ the Statement isn't true.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Does that matter? We are asked to show that it is true for $n\leq 4$ (at least as I interpret the question). What happens for $n\geq 5$ is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: What do you really want to prove? If it's "for integer $n\le4$, $(n+1)^3\le3^n$", then proof by exhaustion is correct and enough. If it's "for integer $n$, $(n+1)^3\le3^n$ if and only if $n\le4$", then there is more work to do. Your statement is not very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a graph to show there is only one intersection between the two lines in the domain $(0,\infty)$.

Or exhaust all cases, which in this case is finite.

Answer (score 1):

You have given a formal proof ! If you want an "overdrawn" proof:

The case $n=4$ is clear. Hence let $n \le 3$. We use the Bernoulli inequality

$$(1+x)^r \ge 1+rx $$

for $r \ge 1$ and $x>-1$. This inequality gives

$$(1+n)^{3/n} \ge 1+\frac{3}{n}n=4.$$

Hence

$$(n+1)^3 \ge 4^n>3^n$$

for $n \le3$.This is more than we want !